# How to turn makefile into JSON Compilation Database?

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, clang, compilation-database

Say we have `make` files  (not cmake/premake/ninja etc) for our project that do work for gcc and clang. We want to generate out from them JSON Compilation Database to feed it into `clang-modernize` tool. How to do such thing? (is there any parser in clang infrastructure or some script with usage like `make CC='cc_args.py gcc' CXX='cc_args.py g++'` or some other tool)?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear? (Which is linked from the clang-modernize site?

Comment: @EtanReisner: That's an answer.

Comment: In my opinion, this a very interesting question. Maybe it was a mistaje to close it. Reards

Comment: I found a compiledb recently. It may help https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb-generator

Comment: `Bear` is an extremely useful tool. Works  cool even for Linux Kernel complicated `Makefiles`.

Comment: Just want to point it out that it's conceptually wrong to list cmake and ninja together.

Answer (score 57):

I have no personal experience with it but [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) seems to be targeted to your scenario. (It was linked from the clang-modernize site.)

Comment: Works great even for Linux kernel modules! Thanks much!

Comment: I am using Bear to generate compilation database for VS Code. Though the compile db looks fine, the VS Code is still not smart enough to find symbol definition with the compile DB. It seems there's still a long way to go for the Intellisense in VS Code. After all, VS code is a folder-based tool. Not a project-based tool like Visual Studio.

Comment: @smwikipedia AFAIK the database isn't used by VS Code directly but rather by an lsp-server it runs, likely `clangd`. So you should look into that. E.g. in my case I have an old large proprietary project at work with lots of targets *(like libs and executables)*. It was Makefile-based until an year ago *(when I moved it to Meson)*. So I've been using Bear + Emacs + clangd as an LSP-server, and it was always working perfectly for me, the "intellisense" in Emacs was always on point.

Answer (score 37):

Make has a usually-undesired feature of emitting the compiler command lines to its standard output, but in this case you can use it with a shell (and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)) pipeline. With [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html#Options-Summary) on Bash:

```sh
make --always-make --dry-run \
 | grep -wE 'gcc|g\+\+' \
 | grep -w '\-c' \
 | jq -nR '[inputs|{directory:".", command:., file: match(" [^ ]+$").string[1:]}]' \
 > compile_commands.json
```

On Windows, `cmd.exe` syntax is similar:

- use `^` instead of `\` for line continuation
- use `"`-delimited strings only
- use `"""` to escape a `"` within a `"`-delimited string
- use `^^` to escape a `^` within a `"`-delimited string

However, this doesn't handle cases where the makefile recursively invokes itself (or other makefiles) in subdirectories using the `-C` argument.

Comment: Had to use `grep -E -w 'gcc|g++'` for the first grep, otherwise I had no results.
For anyone using msys/cygwin replace the jq line with `| jq -nR "[inputs|{directory:\"$(cygpath -m $(pwd))\", command:., file: match(\" [^ ]+$\").string[1:]}]" \ `

Comment: @Teharez Thanks, updated the `grep`. With MSYS2 one might also need to use `mingw32-make` instead of `make`.

Comment: This answer is really good, and if someone use clang like me, try to add gcc|g++|clang in line 2.

Comment: @GGGin There are [many different compilers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) and they should not be mixed in the same build process.

Comment: @Tanz87: `grep -wE 'gcc|g++'` should be `grep -wE 'gcc|g\+\+'`.

Comment: @rtx13 Thanks for spotting!

Comment: After this command in Wine build my `compile_commands.json` has just `[]`, and I had to do a full rebuild because Makefile just disappeared `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`. `bear` from the other answer worked better for me.

Comment: Such I nice answer, that I had to add to my ~/.bash_functions

Comment: You might also want to match on clang: `grep -wE 'gcc|g\+\+|clang|clang\+\+'`

Answer (score 6):

Maybe someone is in my same situation. I have a macOS and [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) was generating an empty `compile_commands.json` file. They acknowledge this problem in the README and suggest to use [scan-build](https://github.com/rizsotto/scan-build) as a workaround. Unfortunately, I was still getting an empty file. Two alternative solutions I found are:

- [compiledb](https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb), which worked in my case.
- a combination of clang++ compiler's `-MJ` option plus sed, detailed [here](https://github.com/Sarcasm/notes/blob/master/dev/compilation-database.rst#clang), that seems simple enough and easy to transform into a `make` target. This one I have not tested.

Comment: How to use Compiledb. I have installed it but unable to find compiledb command in that

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the permission to install Bear/compiledb, or you can't build Bear from source, then a Web app could help.

I built such a simple web app at https://texttoolkit.com/compilation-database-generator, which generates `compile_commands.json` from the make output.

Comment: Nice work, well done.

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't have enough points to react under answers yet, I wanted to comment under @Tanz87 's answer, who suggests to dry-run `make`, and uses `grep` and `jq` to format the output.

My CMake has detected `/usr/bin/c++` as the default compiler (I'm on WSL2, Ubuntu 21.10), and thus the `grep -wE 'gcc|g\+\+'` command does not work, and just like @Hi-Angel, my `compile_commands.json` ended up with `[]`.

The fix is to also grep for `c++`, so the whole command becomes:

```
make --always-make --dry-run \
 | grep -wE 'gcc|g\+\+|c\+\+' \
 | grep -w '\-c' \
 | jq -nR '[inputs|{directory:".", command:., file: match(" [^ ]+$").string[1:]}]' \
 > compile_commands.json
```

Edit: That being said, while the solution does seem to generate a `compile_commands.json` file, running `clang-tidy` in the build directory prints an error from the clang backend for every file in the compilation database:

```
error: no such file or directory: '&&' [clang-diagnostic-error]
```

Every `command` entry in the `compile_commands.json` file looks like this:

```
"cd /build/src && /usr/bin/c++  -I/src/src -std=gnu++2a -o CMakeFiles/project.dir/subdir/subsubdir/sourcefile.cpp.o -c /project/src/subdir/subsubdir/sourcefile.cpp
```

This project uses CMake to generate the Make build system files. Unfortunately, no solution yet.

Edit: Edit: Removing `cd /build/src &&` from each `command` in the `compile_commands.json` fixes that particular error. Using `sed`:

```
sed 's|cd.*.&&||g' compile_commands.json
```

Edit: Edit: Edit: As a oneliner, it requires some extra slashes for the `&&` tokens:

```
make --always-make --dry-run
 | grep -wE 'gcc|g\+\+|c\+\+'
 | grep -w '\-c'
 | sed 's|cd.*.\&\&||g'
 | jq -nR '[inputs|{directory:".", command:., file: match(" [^ ]+$").string[1:]}]' \
 > compile_commands.json
```

Comment: If you're using CMake you can perhaps use its [`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` feature](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I put together this compiler wrapper, you may want to massage the `if` clause which extracts the filename argument. It only detects .c files

I invoke it like this: `make ... CC="cc_wrapper $CC"`

or: `make ... CC="cc_wrapper gcc"`

```
#! /bin/bash

# Writing to a common output file, so buffer for atomic output
if file=($(printf "%s\n" "$@" | grep '\.c$'))
then JSON="$(jq -nR '[inputs|{directory:$pwd, arguments:[$ARGS.positional[]], file:.}]' --arg pwd "$PWD" --args -- "$@" <<< "${file}")"
     # c2rust transpile "$file.compile_commands.json" will still look for a file called compile_commands.json so we have to provide it
     mkdir -p "$file.c2rs"
     echo "$JSON" > "$file.c2rs/compile_commands.json"
fi
exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that for some make projects `compiledb` is able to intercept make output and generate a valid `compile_commands.json` file. However, for some projects it generates an empty `compile_commands.json` file. The solution that always works for me is as below.

```
make clean;make VERBOSE=y all &> make_output.txt
compiledb --parse make_output.txt
```

This always generates a valid compile_commands.json file even for make projects where compiledb is not able to directly intercept the make output.
Hope this helps.

Comment: do you have a link for the `compiledb` software referred?

Comment: Maybe this is it https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb