# how can I make vscode editor aware of preprocessor definitions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am working on an Open Source project that targets multiple platforms. Some files have conditional compilation controlled by symbol definitions in the Makefile. Unfortunately, VSCode editor is not aware of those definitions and often dims code that will be included in the current build.

I have searched for a solution and so far come up with nothing, other than a utility called "bear" (https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear), this doesn't have a Windows package, the OS I am using.

Does anyone know of a solution to this? The various builds are done using VSCode tasks, so being able to integrate something into those would be ideal.
Sid

Comment: The language server for the language you're using should take care of this... no?

Comment: You need to generate `compiler_commands.json` yourself, which isn't hard. The easiest way is to probably do a clean build, dump the build log to a file, do `grep g++` on it, and work from there.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/21134120/11107541